# Wordpress HTML title is messed up

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm unable to get the title in my custom WordPress theme to display properly. The title attribute is set as follows: `<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>`

I took that code straight from the 2012 theme. When I activate the 2012 theme the title looks perfect, but when I use my custom theme with that same code above, I get the address of my website as the title on the homepage, and on every other page, I just get the page name followed by a " | ". Any idea of what could be causing this? Ive looked for second title tags, but so far nothing. Its ruining my SEO.

**Added this to my functions.php:**

```
function twentytwelve_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    global $paged, $page;

    if ( is_feed() )
        return $title;

    // Add the site name.
    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add the site description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        $title = "$title $sep $site_description";

    // Add a page number if necessary.
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        $title = "$title $sep " . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentytwelve' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'twentytwelve_wp_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Did you read this entire page http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title?

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question were you to post a screenshot, or a link to the page (preferably the latter). Also, as mentioned by @j08691, make sure you examine the WordPress Codex closely. They've done a remarkable job of documenting every feature of the CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog name is missing. That's why only the page title is displayed. Try something like this to have an idea:

```
<title>
    <?php
    bloginfo( 'name' );
    echo " | ";
    if ( is_home() ) {
      _e( "Home" );
    }
    else {
      // Get the custom Title for this page, if any.
      if ( defined( 'Title' ) ) {
        $LimitWords = Title;
        echo string_limit_words( $LimitWords, 4 ) . " ...";
      }
      else {
      // Get the default Title
        $LimitWords = wp_title( '', FALSE );
        echo string_limit_words( $LimitWords, 4 ) . " ...";
      }
    }
    ?>
  </title>
```

For that code to work, you have to add this function in `functions.php` in the style sheet directory:

```
  if ( !function_exists( 'string_limit_words' ) ) {
    function string_limit_words( $string, $word_limit ) {
      $words = explode( ' ', $string, ( $word_limit + 1 ) );
      if ( count( $words ) > $word_limit ) array_pop( $words );
      return implode( ' ', $words );
    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean the blog "name" is missing? When switching to another theme, the blog name appears. So wouldn't that mean that the blog name IS set?

Comment: `<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>` That's what is in your question. There, the blog name is missing.

Comment: But that's the exact code from the 2012 theme. And it works fine in the 2012 theme. I understand what you're saying, but now I'm just confused about how 2012 theme works with that code, and my theme doesn't work with it.

Comment: I couldn't say either. Not without seeing it, but try the code in my answer so can have a better idea of what's needed.

Comment: Hrm... I just got it to work. I ctrl + f'ed my way to find a function in the 2012 theme that dealt with the title. I'm updating my post to show what I added. Note: It works great now. Sorry, for wasting your time.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer since you helped lead me in the right direction.